# AngularJS - Content-Disposition Header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-headers

I have a factory which posts data to a webservice.

```
Accept:application/pdf
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1038
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

The server then renders a pdf file and returns it like this.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="angebot.pdf";
Content-Type:application/pdf
Date:Wed, 14 May 2014 16:18:20 GMT
```

What I'm trying to do is, force a download of this pdf file to the filesystem, cross-browser compatible without using an anchor download attribute or something. This is used in an angularjs web app.

Thanks

Comment: sadly, i just used a workaround and used an anchortag which is asynchronously attaches the href to it. Sorry :(